# I'm using primeng auto-complete 5.2.4, I need to display the suggestions on focus of the control

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I'm using primeng auto-complete 5.2.4, I need to display the suggestions on focus of the control.

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="model" [suggestions]="Suggestions" 
  (completeMethod)="filter($event)" field="Value" [required]="true" 
 [forceSelection]="true" [minLength]="0">
</p-autoComplete>
```

I've added the `minLength="0"` and tried various other ways but wasn't successful in displaying the suggestions on focus. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `onFocus` event to call a `show()` like this

```
(onFocus)="autoComplete.show()"
```

but you will need to define the `autoComplete` template to access the `show()`. Full component declaration is:

```
<p-autoComplete
  #autoComplete
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  [suggestions]="Suggestions" 
  (completeMethod)="filter($event)"
  (onFocus)="autoComplete.show()"
  field="Value"
  [required]="true"
  [forceSelection]="true"
  [minLength]="0"></p-autoComplete>
```

You can see a working example here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwpqgp

Comment: can you please post a working example of p-autoComplete in an *ngFor. The onBlur()  and selecting an option doesn't work at times.